# Updating a many to many table. Table does not exist in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a problem with updating a many to many table that does not exist in the edmx diagram.

```
QuestionGroups
PK - QuesitonGroupID

Questions
PK - QuestionID
```

This table does not exist in edmx : I am not able to update this table

```
QuestionGroupQuestions
PK - QuestionGroupID
PK - QuestionID

Answers
PK - AnswerID
```

**This table I am able to update this table correctly**

```
QuestionAnswers
PK - QuestionID
PK - AnswerID
```

Here the code

```
    public ActionResult Create(int questionGroupID, QuestionVM questionVM)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionVM>();

        Question question = Mapper.DynamicMap<Question>(questionVM);

        if (question.Answers != null)
        {
            question.Answers = new List<Answer>();
            foreach (var answer in questionVM.Answers)
            {
                var questionAnswerToAdd = db.Answers.Find(answer.AnswerID);
                question.Answers.Add(questionAnswerToAdd);
            }
        }

        db.Questions.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();


        var questionGroup = db.QuestionGroups.Find(questionGroupID);
        questionGroup.Questions.Add(question);

        db.QuestionGroups.Add(questionGroup);
```

The above code is working.  I do not want to update the QuestionGroup table.  I just want to update the QuestionGroupQuestions table.

```
        db.Entry(questionGroup).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Question");
    }
```

Before the update there are already 2 existing records

```
QuestionGroupID, QuestionID
14,1
14,3
```

When adding a new question I get this error message

{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_QuestionGroupQuestions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.QuestionGroupQuestions'. The duplicate key value is (14, 1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Sounds like you've already got a row with that PK; no? Do you need to remove those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when mapping tables with many-to-many relation(`QuestionGroups` and `Questions`), the table which holds related ID's (`QuestionGroupQuestions`) does not maps to any entity, instead of it the other tow table is mapped to entities with many-to-many association, the association is a collection of instances from each other inside them, and when save any valid changes of these tow tables the EF automatically updates the third table (`QuestionGroupQuestions`) so it's not need to update QuestionGroupQuestions.

```
var questionGroup = db.QuestionGroups.Find(questionGroupID);
questionGroup.Questions.Add(question);
//The problem is here that you are adding questionGroup again. comment it and check
//db.QuestionGroups.Add(questionGroup); this cause a error, questionGroup already exists
```

now if you save the changes to `db` the QuestionGroupQuestions tables also should get updated.